# Approved edit removed a lot of code, is this ok?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

Revision 6 on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21525455/revisions removed an entire class from the question code. The answers don't really need the class to make sense, but I find the edit too radical.

In response, the original asker added the edited-out code as an answer. What to do in this situation?

Comment: He didn't remove the class, but suggested the edit before the OP added the class. Just add it back and the problem is solved.

Comment: Why would the person who re-added that section of code put "improved formatting" as the [revision note](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3963589) -.- begging to get rejected

Comment: @OGHaza auto complete. People write the reason once then just fill this same reason for all eternity, too lazy to write something else.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ahhh yeah, that makes sense

Comment: @Antony want to add that as an answer so I can close this question? It's bothering me :D